# Android Canvas Graphics

Tags: java, android, canvas, graphics, bitmap

I'm extremely new to Android development, but I have lots of experience with Java. What I'd like to know is how to independently draw on a View using a Canvas object.

What I want is an Android equivalent of this Java code:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(whateverImage, 0, 0, null);
g = frame.getGraphics(); /*just pretend 'frame' is a JFrame that we're using*/
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
```

Basically all that code does is make a blank bitmap image, draw on that image, then draw the bitmap onto a JFrame to display it.

I'm aware that Android doesn't use BufferedImage or Graphics, but I believe that the Android pseudo-equivalents are Bitmap and Canvas, respectively.

The problem is that when I have code that like this:..

```
Bitmap guy = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.guy);
Canvas c = new Canvas(Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
c.drawBitmap(guy, 0, 0, null);
```

...I take it that the same concept of a blank bitmap being created and then drawn on occurs. However, I don't know how to then draw the Canvas onto a View, SurfaceView, or some other method that will display it on my device's screen.

It's important to note that I do *not* want to `@Override` `onDraw` and use it to draw my graphics, as I would like to control the drawing independently using some sort of thread loop.

If I did not provide enough information or my question is nonsensical, feel free to either ask me about it or ignore it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Also, if anybody has any tips, tutorials, references, or anything else to better my understanding of layouts, views, etc. that would be greatly appreciated as well. Like I said, I am very inexperienced and trying to learn.*

**EDIT: Now working. Thanks :)** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugWlu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to draw onto a View is to override onDraw.  What you can do though is draw to an in memory bitmap (like you do here) in any other function, then draw the bitmap to the screen in onDraw.  Just do

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawBitmap(inMemoryBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. While this is the most obvious answer, my problem is still that `onDraw` is called according to the system's timing, and I would like the framerate/update speed to be in my control. Can I use the `invalidate()` method on every render loop to force call `onDraw` and redraw the screen, or is that not recommended?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using invalidate.  onDraw isn't called at a certain update rate-  its called as needed.  If nothing invalidates the screen, nothing is drawn.  (when you call setText or similar methods on views, those functions call invalidate for you).